# Cannot get the selected text from a dropdown using jquery in a script editor in SharePoint 2013

Tags: jquery, dropdown

The following Snippet Code only alerts "Status = ".  The code does not retrieve the value/text.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function getStatus() {
  var statusVal = $("select[title='Status'] option:selected").text();
  alert("Status = ",statusVal);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  getStatus();
}); 

</script>
```

Comment: can you check browser console for any error ?

Answer (score 0):

That isn't how alert works. It should be:

`alert("Status = "+statusVal);`

If you run `$("select[title='Status'] option:selected").text()` in the console of your browser is it returning the right value?

Comment: Thank you, the alert syntax was the issue!!!  This fixed it.